# Cannot create EntityManager from valid persistence.xml

Tags: scala, jpa, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to use JPA from Play 2.0 Scala application. In my code I have:

```
val factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("devcrowd")
```

I also have `persistence.xml` in package `META-INF`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="devcrowd" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="xxxx"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="xxxx"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/devcrowd"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This persistence.xml seems valid to me, but the factory cannot be created:

```
PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named devcrowd
```

Comment: To less stack trace. Check if postgresql jdbc is in classpath.

Comment: And hibernate, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the Hibernate library/ies at deploy time.